# Dual boot with windows 10 not working on a Lenovo Thinkpad Carbon

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, lenovo

I am trying to install a fresh Ubuntu 16 OS onto a computer - Lenovo Thinkpad X1 with Win10. I chose all the standard options on install, and ubuntu was installed, but no grub came up on startup. I made all the standard changes to Win10 before the installation like disable fast startup, make sure UEFI boot was enabled, secure boot is off. I used boot repair and get the following pastebin report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DhsHXfFHnW/ Still no grub. My one time boot menu does not specify if the USB is uefi or not. I have already set bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi to make sure that the grub is given preference over windows bootloader. Am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps you've missed the fact that "Ubuntu 16 OS" might be too old for that machine. With only about 3 months of support left, why not try something newer?

Comment: I work on legacy systems that need me to be on the older OS. Also its LTS period is still not over so technically it is still supported.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is specifically for people using Lenovo products or Think brand products. When I get into the BIOS I do not see an option to choose for a UEFI boot for the Liveboot USB. I suspected that it was legacy booting this drive as it was legacy compatible. I re-created a live USB with *UEFI only* boot. That alone did the trick. I do not think this would apply to other companies as BIOS menus and their behaviours might be different.

Answer (score 0):

- ★ In BIOS Setting, You find boot order. put ubuntu top of the list.
- save changes and reboot pc
- boot in ubuntu.
- open a terminal and write the below command.

```
sudo update-grub
```

- This command updates the boot list and adds windows to grub list also.

---

I hope your problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem during installation in my new Lenovo IdeaPad 5 15ITL05.

Follow these steps.

1. Open Windows 10 , unallocate memory for Ubuntu and restart it by pressing the Shift key.
2. Go to BIOS.
3. Enable Secure Boot (Disable might work for you).
4. Change the boot device to USB flash drive.
5. Go to flash drive and press install Ubuntu.
6. Install Ubuntu with first option (Install Ubuntu alongside with Windows 10 to enable the grub loader during booting).
7. After installation I faced problem like no sound, no mouse touchpad & no control over brightness.
8. I ran `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, but the no sound, no mouse touchpad & no control over brightness problem still exists.
9. Update using the GUI interface.